# assigning javascript variable to jsp in the same page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to assign a javascript variable to jsp. I am doing this by submitting a html hidden field inside a form to server.

But finally the value in jsp is alwasy `null`. These jsp code and javascript are in the same page. Please have a look a the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form  action= "Custom_DHTMLDashboard_Content.jsp" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="hiddenField"    />
            document.getElementById("hiddenField").value = reportID;
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<%String MyID = (request.getParameter("hiddenField"));%>
alert("this is scriptlet" + "<%=MyID%>");//always null
```

Comment: the `alert("this is scriptlet" + "<%=MyID%>");//always null` should also come in a `<script>` tag. I think it would be really better to learn the concepts of JSP and Servlets first, here is a good starting tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Put `<script>` tags around your script (`document.getElementById("hiddenField").value = reportID;`)
2. Define `reportID` somewhere (before you try to use it)
3. **Escape** the data you output with `<%=MyID%>`. Outputting unfiltered, unescaped data to the page is how you make [XSS vulerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

If you fix that then:

- The first time you load the page, `<%=MyID%>` will be null
- When you submit the form, it will have a value